# Cannot display images in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have multiple images instead of importing each image in my content.js like this eg:

`import myimg1 from './myimg1.png'`

`import myimg2 from './myimg2.png'`

`import myimg3 from './myimg3.png'`

`import myimg4 from './myimg4.png'`

I have made images.js and then imported each image inside images.js and exported it so that I can access those images in content.js:

images.js:

```
import java from './images/java.png';
import neural from './images/neural.png';
import logo from './images/logo.png';
import dsa from './images/dsa.png';
import dl from './images/dl.jpeg';
import ds from './images/ds.jpeg';
import boy from './images/boy.jpeg';
import ml from './images/ml.jpeg';
import phone from './images/phone.png';

export default {
    java,
    logo,
    dsa,
    dl,
    ds,
    boy,
    ml,
    neural,
    phone
}
```

In content.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import images from './images';

<img src={images.java} alt="Java" height="65" width="65"></img>

 <img src={images.neural} alt="Neural Network" height="65" width="65"></img>
```

I have made images folder which contains all images but I am not able to access the images and display it in content.js component.

[image]

Comment: What will be the result of, for example, `images.java`?

Comment: @HuyVo I am using images.java in src="" check in the question

Comment: Have you tried to console.log `images.java`? The reason it doesn't render your image is because `images.java` is null.

Comment: @HuyVo I think you did not got my question I am importing all images from images folder inside images.js component and then exporting it to content.js but it is not working.

Comment: The reason it's not working is that you either imported or exported it the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See there is no class named `images`  in your `images.js`, so

```
import images from './images'
```

will do nothing in `content.js`...So try this way

**images.js**

```
import java from './images/java.png';
import logo from './images/logo.png';

export {
    java,
    logo
}
```

**content.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { java, logo } from './images';

<img src={java} alt="" height="65" width="65">
<img src={logo} alt="" height="65" width="65">
```

Comment: Can you post the same answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229529/how-to-add-multiple-images-from-external-js-file-in-reactjs I will upvote :)

Comment: @stonerock Glad it helped you..!..See there is no need to post the same answer on same question...I think you should delete the previous question...

Answer (score 0):

the export `default` is just used for when there is only one import function, in your case you should do export without `default`

```
export {
    java,
    logo,
    dsa,
    dl,
    ds,
    boy,
    ml,
    neural,
    phone
}
```

Then, in your file, you'd import all inside brackets

```
import { java, logo, dsa.. } from './yourFilePath'
```

Comment: See the screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/NkedO it is saying export default.

Comment: I also made following changes in code see multiple screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/NlqNf

Comment: I think you did not got my question I am importing all images from images folder inside images.js component and then exporting it to content.js but it is not working.

Comment: if you look at this answer, is the same answer than @Bhuwan